# php check online offline user status simply

Tags: php, status

What is the best method to check if user is online or offline?
in PHP,there is both functions:

```
time();
```

and

```
strtotime();
```

how to use them to check status ?

Comment: As yet this isn't an appropriate question for SO.  Perhaps you could take your non-working answer, edit it into the question and ask for guidance as to where your approach is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simple,to check the user status,do the following:

1-in each file of the website (like database file or session file),make a query to update last activity of user using `time()` function.

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    $uid=$_SESSION['id'];
    $now=time();
    $update=$db->prepare("update users set last_act=$now where uid='$uid'");
    $update->execute();
}
```

In profile page,or any page you want to display status of the users,get the `last_activity` record of the user,and the `time()` now,then subtract them,and if the difference is more than 300 (which is the difference in seconds),so the user is offline,else the user is online.

```
if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {
    $now = time();
    if (is_int($_GET['pid'])) {
        $userid = $_GET['pid'];
    }

    $get_last_act = $db->prepare("select last_act from users where uid='$userid' ");
    $get_last_act->execute();
    $fetch = $get_last_act->fetch();
    $last_act = $fetch['last_act'];
    $difference = $now - $last_act;
    if ($difference > 300) {
        echo 'offline';
    }
    else {
        echo 'online';
    }
}
```

Comment: A prepared statement is quite worthless if you don't use placeholders.  You are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: `var_dump(is_int('2'));` outputs `bool(false)`, is_int is a type test.  $userid will not be set.  Did you try your code?